# How to solve 'TypeError: $location.absUrl is not a function' error in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I am working on a legacy AngularJS application and currently just upgraded to AngularJS 1.7.6. The application uses ui-router and in `angular.module().config` we have some code that uses `$location.absUrl.`

I know `$location` can't be injected in normal way to module.config so we are using the `$injector` as suggested on ui-router website. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing

However, `$location.absUrl` always return the above error on the title. according to AngularJs documentation, `$location.absUrl` is still supported in Angular 1.7.6. I hope someone could point me out the right direction.

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function ($injector, $location){
        var url = $location.absUrl();            

        if (url.indexOf('/admin') !== -1) {
            $location.path("/admin");
        }
        else {
            $location.path("home");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please not the tags, `angular`-tag refers to version 2++

Comment: ah ok. .............